# Remove cache entries by prefix

Tags: playframework-2.0, ehcache, prefix

**EDIT**
Circumflex accesses [ehcache's getKeys](https://github.com/inca/circumflex/blob/master/circumflex-cache/src/main/scala/cache.scala#L120), so it should be possible to do similar in Play, provided the Cache plugin implementation exposes getKeys, which may not be possible (that would assume every Cache library provides a means to query for all keys in the cache)

**ORIGINAL**
Is there a way to remove cache entries by key prefix with EhCache?

I'm using Play framework's cache implementation which uses EhCache by default.

Looking at Play 2 Scala Cache.scala I see a remove method that takes a string, the key to delete, but am wondering if EhCache itself supports removal by prefix (if so, I'll make a feature request to Play devs for 2.1 snapshot)

As it stands, I'm using a helper method that takes a list of common cache keys and removes matches:

```
object clear {
  def apply(key: String, keys: List[String] = List()) = {
    if(keys.size > 0) keys.filter(_.startsWith(key)) map(Cache.remove(_))
    else Cache.remove(key)
  }
}
```

but maintaining a list of fixed keys is silly compared to passing any key prefix directly to Cache remove

Answer (score 5):

According to the [EHCache plugin](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cache.scala#L116), you also have direct access to EHCache, just by using the [CacheManager.create()](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#create%28%29) static methods:

```
net.sf.ehcache.Cache cache = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create().getCache("play");
```

The `create()` method returns the existing instance if one exists.

Comment: Nice Nico, but I'd like to play with Play Cache plugin directly if possible.

Comment: So you'll have to write your own cache plugin: as @biesior said, for the moment, the Play Cache API only contains `set`, `get` and `remove`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately current implementation of EhCache in Play is quite basic and it's limited to operations like `put cache entry` and `delete cache entry`. Pity.

On the other hand EhCache delivers much more sophisticated ways for managing cache entries, including making it searchable by custom fields, indexes etc, so it's possible to create http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/search .

Of course that was brilliant if it was implemented in Play *out-of-the-box*, but I can imagine developers' point of view: '*Making every feature used sub-system available in Play would kill the lightness of the framework*' - that's my guess and I agree with that.

So best hit in this case would be just creating a new module for Play, let's call it *CachePlus*, which would incorporate the features of EC on the demand. Anyway *somebody* has to start it and share with others :)

Comment: it's probably minimal because it has to support any cache implementation, not just EhCache -- not sure if Redis et al support a getKeys accessor, but if so, would be nice if Play exposed that method! (I posted to Play user group where it will likely get lost in the sea of posts...)

Comment: In my opinion the Play! team should extends the trait "CacheAPI" with a simple wrapper method (something like getWrappedCacheObject()), which returns the original cache object. The user can cast it into EhCache or whatever and use the original implementation with all of the functionailty or the user doesn't use the original cache object to stay clean and independent of a cache implementation. Everyone will be happy. :-)